# How to handle selected, reselected tabs using SlidingTabLayout and SlidingTabStrip?

Tags: android, android-tabs

I'm working in an application that uses `SlidingTabLayout` and `SlidingTabStrip` and what I want to do is handle when I select a tab and the fragment is changed.

I have read something about `ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener` and `ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener` and tried both, but none of them seems to work and don't know why.

Comment: you can simply relay on the adapter that you are using

Comment: share the relevant code in the question

Comment: removed tag from title, improve grammar, formatting

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Did you set the ViewPager for your SlidingTabLayout?

```
//Get reference to SlidingTabLayout and ViewPager from layout
mSlidingTabLayout.setViewPager(mPager);

ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener pageChangeListener = new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener(){
            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                super.onPageSelected(position);
                pageSelected = position;
            }
};
mSlidingTabLayout.setOnPageChangeListener(pageChangeListener);
mPager.setCurrentItem(pageSelected);
mPager.setAdapter(mAdapter); //Set your FragmentPagerAdapter
```

Comment: This worked very well, what I was doing was setting the SimpleOnPageChangeListener into the ViewPager, that's why it wasn't working